# Google Sheets Query Error: Query Not Returning proper Array value when a condition is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to solve why one of the Google Sheets I maintain is failing to operate properly. I've isolated that the issue is with a query

`QUERY(Import_MJL!A:BU, "select A where AJ> 0")`

For reference the Import_MJL sheet is a static database. The AJ column holds a currency value. When performing an IF function of that column, it returns as TRUE as seen here

`if(Import_MJL!AJ2 > 0,1,0)`

What could be the reason that the query is not recognizing when my AJ Column is above 0 ?

Screenshot for bellow reference. Row 1 holds the code & row 2 holds the Results (The B2 Cell should result in an array whose length is over 10K but only returns the header. The Import_MJL!AJ2 cell has value 38K and should be a result of the cell on B2)

[Screenshot of code and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQBIS.png)

Thanks for the time y'all!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that `Import_MJL!AJ2` does not contain a number but the *text string* `$38,738.00` that only looks like a number. Many spreadsheet functions will automatically convert such values into numbers, but `query()` will not.

You can check whether a value is actually a number with the `isnumber()` function.

Here's a quick fix to try:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { Import_MJL!A1:AI, value(Import_MJL!AJ1:AJ), Import_MJL!AK1:BU }, 
    "select Col1 where Col36 > 0", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the help!